# paymentsRequest.stream

Tags: java-sdk, new-developer, android

I'm using the android studio and
I'm having trouble with paymantsRequest.stream.
it's saying it can't connect to server sent event.
(cannot access com.here.oksse.serversentevent)

here is the code
https://github.com/NanneStephan/android-stellar-sdk/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/org/stellar/android/sample/StellarAsync.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it : ).
needed to add
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0' and
implementation 'com.github.heremaps:oksse:0.9.0'
in the build.gradle for the sample.